# MongoDB cannot find nested objects

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

```
[ { _id: 5bd109d0920e2f4e9d786866,
started: false,
round: 0,
host:
 { userid: 'uc',
   ready: false,
   playerTable: [Array],
   enemyTable: [Array] },
challenger:
 { userid: 'iki',
   ready: false,
   playerTable: [Array],
   enemyTable: [Array] } } ]
```

Here is all includings of a collection.

```
y.collection("games").find({host:{userid: 'uc'}}).toArray(console.log)
```

And here is my query. However, this query gives

```
null []
```

Where am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't access nested fields like this **{host:{userid**.


Instade use
**y.collection("games").find({"host.userid": "uc"}})**
to get the documents.

Answer (score 0):

Well. Since this user and challengers objects inside the document are subdocuments, we should query them as if y.collection("games").find({"host.userid":'uc'})